# The component is not re-rendered after linking on react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a dropdown menu (maked on select/option) in my header. As planned, when user choose item in dropdown menu, react-router will change URL and make rerender page. I have a mistake on last stage. URL changes, but page not rerender

[Link to SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-edison-gmykk?file=/src/components/SelectRouter/SelectRouter.jsx)

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: The `BrowserRouter` you are using in `SelectRouter` only wraps the select. The `BrowserRouter` contains a context that is used by `Link` and `Route` components. To fix this issue you should remove the `BrowserRouter` from `SelectRouter` and add it to your `App` ensuring that both the `Header` and the `Route` is a child (nested or direct) of the `BrowserRouter`

Comment: @JacobSmit, It's work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

All Route and Links Components should by wrapped by BrowserRouter, easiest way to do that is to wrap everything in your App.js return statement by BrowserRouter Component.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Stats from "./pages/Stats/Stats";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />

        <Route path="/stats" exact>
          <Stats />
        </Route>
      </div>
    </ Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a `<Swtich>` with routes to select where the matched routes will rendered. And wrap all of that in the `<BrowserRouter>` or `<HashRouter>`.

```
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Header />

    <Switch>
      <Route path="/stats" component={Stats}></Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```

[Link to the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-oskar-7xo24?file=/src/App.js:269-445)

Comment: `Switch` is not required to render routes. `Switch` is used to render the first route that is matched only and not any subsequent routes that might also be matched.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. But I assume that's what he wants to do